# Is FCM notification reliable or not in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I am working on FCM notification in my android application.I am having a issues that there are some users who are not getting the notification and those respective notification is being lost.I just want to know what are the scenarios in which the FCM notification can missed out?

Sometimes messages are received within a few seconds, sometimes after a few minutes (could even be over 10 and even 20 minutes!), and sometimes not at all...

This is happening randomly - for example, a message could be received immediately, and a message sent right after it will only be received after 10 minutes.

I have set the priority of the messages to high, and time-to-live to maximum to make sure the messages are not discarded.

I have no problem in time delayed by FCM but i want to know in which scenarios these notification is missing?

Comment: I think something depend on the speed of the network? So far I doesn't have any missing notification in my app. Just delay problem, I have test out 1mbps,4,8,30 mbps network. 4,8,30 mbps network never got delay message at all. But sometimes while i watching youtube 1mbps are not even receive any notification until I restart the emulator. Still maybe sometime is regarding tokenRefresh issues. If you say you need a really reliable I think XMPP server which is more reliable and FCM support XMPP server as well.

Comment: @teckwei Thanks for giving time on my issue.But i was using the GCM earlier, now i have implemented FCM. I want to ask is there any chances that now those notification can be missed out? Or should i switched to XMPP server for more reliablity?

Comment: FCM using based on GCM core but more reliable, so if there is no problem in your GCM impossible something happen in FCM as long as your configuration setting up correctly. If you not create something like chat application which require 99.99% reliable you should be fine just use pure HTTP.  XMPP server is kinda a hard to setup espcially when you just get started, you can start to learn it then you decide what to do. Still there will be some chance it will missed out due to something we don't expected.